# Depth of field in animation

Tags: animation

Would like to know the way of blurring the background in an animation....i.e.depth of field. Not getting it to work with animation. Works with single frame.
Any help would be great.
I have set the depth of field option in shading to depth of field.
I have set the f stop to low numbers...from 0.02 to 1.0
I have selected/deselect an object ... a barrel. I want the barrel in focus and every thing else blurred.
It works in the preview but when i render it doesn't show the blur.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We can't guess how you set up your project or your depth of field settings.

Comment: If possible, could you upload a .blend showing the problem?

Comment: Again, without information is hard to help. Which render engine are you using? Did you set the depth of of field for the camera? We can't guess what your scene looks like. Add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings. Additionally, consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.